# Django: filtering the database and templates

Tags: python, django, filter

I am importing csv files into Django models and then displaying them as simple tables. What I want is to have filter boxes for the users on the website where they can enter, for example: 
Game name, Date, Country, etc
and the tables will be filtered based on what the user entered (if the data exists of course)

I have been researching what is better to use, and still haven't come up with a solution. What I am considering is [this](https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) or [this](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). Although I am not sure. This question might be very trivial, but I would really appreciate some advice!

Also there should be multi filtering of data available - so that a user can filter by date and then filter, let's say, by country. And the filter keywords are either entered by user, or they are already there like buttons (besides dates I guess)

Thanks again, will appreciate any help!

Comment: There are two approaches you can use: filter server-side and re-render the template, or do your filtering client-side using JavaScript.

Comment: may you provide some links to those approaches (more specific)?

Comment: An example of client-side filtering would be: http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/#datagrid

Comment: Server-side filtering would be, for example, passing a filter value through the querystring. You can see an example of that in Django admin if you set the `list_filter` attribute of a model admin to a property on your model.

Comment: Ok, I see, so for server side filtering I would use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224623/django-filtering-the-database-and-templates?noredirect=1#comment33746522_22224623
right?

Comment: Sure. S.O. uses various URL segments to filter questions, these are represented as "tags" to the end user. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#filter

Comment: would your advice though be using server-side approach?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49153/discussion-between-brandon-and-yudasinal)